# p-adic Norms and Character Values

Tags: representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a group with a $\mathbb{Q}_p$-representation $\mathfrak{X}: G \to \mbox{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ affording the character $\chi$. We have the $p$-adic norm $\| \cdot \|$ defined on an extension field $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ generated by the $|G|$-th roots of unity.

I wonder whether $\chi(g)\chi(g^{-1}) = |\chi(g)|^2$ for all $g \in G$ in this situation as is true for $\mathbb{C}$-representations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is trivially correct when $n = 1$: the left side is $1$ and the right side is $|\chi(g)|_p^2$, which is $1$ since $\chi(g)$ is a root of unity when $n = 1$.

Is is never true for all $g$ when $n > 1$: at $g = 1$, your desired equation turns into $d^2 = |n|_p^2$, which is incorrect since $n^2$ is an integer greater than $1$ while $|n|_p \leq 1$.

In $\mathbf C$ we can write $|z|^2$ as $z\overline{z}$, but there is nothing like that for $p$-adic fields since $p$-adic absolute values are (positive) real numbers while the values of the characters are in $p$-adic fields.  Even in cases where $\chi(g) = 0$, so both sides of your proposed equation are $0$, it would be strange to regard the $p$-adic number $0$ as the real number $|0|_p$. (Yes, we do identify $\mathbf Q$ with its images in $\mathbf R$ and every $\mathbf Q_p$, but I think that is missing my point.)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but what is $d$ here?

Comment: @pancini  yes.  I misread the small font in the target group.  I've now changed $d$ to $n$ in my answer.

Comment: This helps a lot. I am reading a book on modular representation theory, and the authors make use of the the claim I'm asking about, despite working exclusively with $p$-adic characters.

Comment: What is the book and where is the first place in the book where this is used?

Comment: This would be *Modular Representations of Finite Groups* by Dixon & Puttaswamaiah. I believe the first instance of this is in the example in 3.7 (pg 83). I still believe the result there holds since the character values are algebraic over the prime subfield of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, so they might be implicitly referring to the real absolute value instead of the $p$-adic absolute value, since the character values lie in a field isomorphic to a subfield of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Comment: I don't have access to that book now.  Could you please include details you're asking about in the body of your question, to make the question more self-contained?